# Youtube Live Video embedding not allowed

Tags: youtube-livestreaming-api, obs

I want to embed a Youtube Live Video inside a webpage. Some years ago this was not a further problem. At the weekend I created a new Youtube account for a sports club and Livestreaming was activated 24h after verification. Now I set "allow embedding" for the Livestream, but every time I create an Event with OBS and stream to this event, the "allow embedding" option is disabled. An older installation for another sports club has this option enabled every time I stream.

Once the Livestream is startet it is possible to change the option via YouTube Studio, but it should be the default.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The moment you start the live stream the "allow embedded" is switched off. If you immediately after going live (during your intro video or waiting video) switch it back on again on the youtube website it works fine. But it is indeed an irritating bug.

Comment: It is indeed - i wish i have found this out **before** 1000ish people informed me simultaneously via event support chat